# Discrepancy PyCharm - Google Colab

Tags: python, pycharm, google-colaboratory, conv-neural-network

I am doing a project on self-driving cars (using the Udacity open-source simulator). I have been experimenting with Google Colab and I am getting a lot of errors that I don't get if I run the exact same code on my PC. I guessed it all had to do with the way I uploaded the data, so I repeated the process in many different ways, but I seem unable to figure it out.

This is the code for reference: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/123Q-1e8Csl6xYw_DfVTejtw0oozUjj7
(This time I got the data the same way he did: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W5I8NYsavde4iy-1uiztNKwwYw7_Pfs_).

Anyways, you can see that I get this error: `Error when checking input: expected cropping2d_9_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 64, 1)` that I don't get with the exact same code on Pycharm.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert (reshape) your input shape in to a 4-dimensional array.

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 64, 64, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 64, 64, 1)
```

Comment: hi! Thanks for your answer! I am getting `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4096 into shape (64,64,64,1)`.